# Can't find getPackageManager() method in android

Tags: android

I have problem with my project.

I can't find `getPackageManager()` method although i imported  `android.content.pm.PackageManager;`

what wrong with this piece of code

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

.Thanks for your helping

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Is your class extends with FragmentActivity, Activity or Fragment???

Answer (score 80):

The error is not in your line of code, but where you are calling it.  `getPackageManager()` is  a method of Context.  You can use this method inside an Activity (because an Activity is a Context), but if you are calling it elsewhere, you need to pass a Context. In a fragment you may also have access to the getActivity() function, which returns the Acitivity-Context.

```
    Context context...;

    context.getPackageManager();
    getActivity().getPackageManager();
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using it in Activity you will not get an error or warning for `getPacketManager`, but if you are using it in Fragments you should prefix it with `getActivity`.

**example:**

`PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();`

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

I guess you are **extends** is  `Fragment`

So, you have to use `getActivity().getPackageManager()` like below

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getActivity().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Or **extends** is `BroadcastReceiver`

In side `onReceive` you have to use `context.getPackageManager()` like below

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this may be due to `Context`

If you are using

**Activity :** Then you can directly access this method by importing `android.content.pm.PackageManager;`

If you are using **Fragment :** Then you need to provide `getActivity()` to avail method

**I.E.**

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getActivity().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Comment: @user3418401 If it works for you then you can mark and upvote it so any other developer can get solution quickly.

Comment: @RonakMehta I m using AsyncTask, can you suggest what context I should use??

Comment: @Asahish, Please use Activity Context here.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try context.getPackageManager() if you have context passed as a parameter in your class constructor eg for Broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

yep.
if you extends fragment use `getActivity().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);`
else `context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);`

Answer (score 0):

If using Jetpack Compose with Kotlin, use `LocalContext.current.packageManager`