# React native how to get "getPackageManager()"

Tags: java, react-native

do you know how to get acces to getPackageManager() (for java) in react-native please? I searched everywhere but I only found some errors with getPackageManager()... I need this to know if my app has been downloaded from the Play Store or by other method. (I can't say Hi at the beginning of my post, I'm polite normaly:))

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find getPackageManager() method in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396382/cant-find-getpackagemanager-method-in-android)

Comment: It's for android in java, I need it in react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the react native application context and get the package manager from there.

```
PackageManager manager = reactContext.getPackageManager();
```

or just get it from the current activity

```
Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
PackageManager manager = currentActivity.getPackageManager();
```

Comment: Thank you Sven, I will check it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the react native application context and get the package manager. However, I used the `getReactApplicationContext` method to get the context. So the answer becomes:

```
PackageManager pm = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
```