# Check Google Play Services version in React Native app

Tags: react-native

How can I programmatically check which version of Google Play Services is installed in a React Native app?

Comment: you should use Native module in java else if u have some third party module then use that.  check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958689/react-native-how-to-get-getpackagemanager