# Why can't it find getPackageManager?

Tags: java, android

I have tried to open the Gmail app via this:

```
import android.content.Intent;


public class GmailApp {
    public static void OpenGmail() {

        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
        if(intent != null){
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

It says it can't find it.
But how?

I've read this article right here [Can't find getPackageManager() method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396382/cant-find-getpackagemanager-method-in-android)

But I don't understand it.

Can anyone give me an example code that will work?

Comment: See if this answers your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470042/intent-uri-to-launch-gmail-app

Comment: `getPackageManager` is a method on a `Context`, which your class is not... Pass in a context if you want to call that. It's literally the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22396570/9473786) in the question you linked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find getPackageManager() method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396382/cant-find-getpackagemanager-method-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

There are many potential causes for the symptoms you are describing, but one potential cause is the package visibility restrictions introduced in Android 11.

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/automatic

Try adding this to your manifest:

```
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.gm" />
    </queries>
```